# Creating a spit view app from single view ios

Tags: ios, ipad

I have run into a snag with changing a single view style app into a split view style app.

I have made it so I have the detail view set to the correct view controller, but dont know how to set up a table view for the master view. I created the table view as its own file outside of the storyboard and I don't know how to add it to the master view.

Also how should I link the two together in my code? The Table View was displayed as a popover in the single view version of the app, and it calls a method from the View Controller when a cell is selected. How would I implement the code to bind them?

Sorry if this seems noobish, but this is my first app and still learning.